# Calling an Azure web service from Silverlight with more than 16 KB of data

Tags: wcf, silverlight, azure

I call an Azure (WCF) web service from a Silverlight application. Silverlight only supports basicHttpBinding so my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://(AzureUri)/Services.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServices"
                contract="WebServices.IServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that the Silverlight application crashes with the infamous "NotFound" error message when making a call to the Azure web service with more than 16384 bytes of data, obviously hitting one of the limitations.

But basicHttpBinding does not support attributes like maxBytesPerRead, maxStringContentLength, so I don't know how I can allow calls to the Azure web service with more than 16 KB of data.

Googling has just confused me more, so any help is appreciated...

Thanks for your time,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server configuration, make sure the **bindingConfiguration** attribute of the **endpoint** element inside the **service** element correctly points to the name of the binding. Also verify that the **binding** element points to "basicHttpBinding". In general, carefully review all the names, because if one of them is mispelled or missing, you'll end up with the default configurations in the server.

For a complete example see [Retrieving huge amount of data from WCF service in Silverlight application](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/).

Comment: I have solved the issue using your suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. This can be really confusing and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This seems promising: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/retrieving-huge-amount-of-data-from-wcf-service-in-silverlight-application/

Comment: While Googling I came across this one, but it is about a WCF service not about a Windows Azure service...

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track thinking about it as a "Windows Azure service". It is a WCF service running under IIS running under a Windows Server instance that is managed by Azure. Azure itself will not interfere in the way this WCF service works. I suggest you recheck your client and server configuration; look for a Web.config inside a directory, if your service is inside a directory. Look for misspelled names (see my other answer). Look for Web.Release.config.

Comment: I have solved the issue using your suggestions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

(Cross-posted on MSDN since I got no answer and it's urgent...)

I think the problem is in the fact that the web service is running in Azure.

• If the service runs locally I can pass more than 16 KB of data to it.
• If the service runs in Azure I get the message: "The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data".

But I have the following settings in the Web.config of the service:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAzureServices"
                   maxBufferPoolSize     ="2147483647"
                   maxBufferSize         ="2147483647"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <readerQuotas  maxArrayLength        ="2147483647"
                   maxBytesPerRead       ="2147483647"
                   maxDepth              ="2147483647"
                   maxNameTableCharCount ="2147483647"
                   maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

So, it seams that the maxBufferSize setting is ignored when the service runs in Azure.